# How much more it will take for Ethereum wallet to Sync - 2019

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, mainnet

I has been a week when I tried to Sync Ethereum on SSD VPS. Here are the details -

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             4
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 62
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 v2 @ 2.20GHz
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               2200.000
BogoMIPS:              4400.00
Hypervisor vendor:     VMware
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              25600K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm cpuid_fault pti ibrs ibpb stibp fsgsbase tsc_adjust smep arat arch_capabilities
```

Memory -

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          16040        1174        7237         134        7628       14340
Swap:           974         654         320
```

Total `.ethereum` folder size - 140 GB

eth.syncing -

`{
  currentBlock: 8907612,
  highestBlock: 8907703,
  knownStates: 75477558,
  pulledStates: 75476506,
  startingBlock: 8904137
}`

Last few lines of geth logs -

```
INFO [11-11|00:14:44.104] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=9.572ms    number=8907938 hash=f24302…d66ebc age=8h19m36s
WARN [11-11|00:14:44.719] Pivot became stale, moving               old=8907809 new=8907874
INFO [11-11|00:14:44.920] Imported new block receipts              count=65   elapsed=199.550ms  number=8907873 hash=ed103f…bf3827 age=8h32m32s size=2.93MiB
INFO [11-11|00:14:47.654] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=9.373ms    number=8907939 hash=a79b7e…6281ef age=8h19m36s
INFO [11-11|00:15:01.027] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=7.654ms    number=8907940 hash=00fa81…6a460e age=8h19m47s
INFO [11-11|00:15:24.354] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=124.532ms  number=8907941 hash=2185b6…89572a age=8h20m7s
INFO [11-11|00:15:27.805] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=19.271ms   number=8907942 hash=758d67…048800 age=8h20m7s
INFO [11-11|00:15:34.629] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=10.442ms   number=8907943 hash=17d7a5…5a7b06 age=8h20m3s
```

Command used to run geth - `geth` (without any sync options)

Is something I am Missing here ? Or how much time it should take more ?

Comment: For Ethereum mainnet you can get an idea with: https://github.com/hayorov/ethereum-sync-metrics. You need to modify the `metrics.py` file and set `NUM_OF_STATES  = 379265938` (oct 11, 2019 https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15616#issuecomment-541288656)

Comment: Thanks for your response @alberto . I read the link you mentioned. Can you please explain why I need to edit `metrics.py` file manually ?

Comment: Because the `NUM_OF_STATES` variable of this file is not updated (as you can see here: https://github.com/hayorov/ethereum-sync-metrics/blob/master/metrics.py#L11). This variable increases over time.